# OrientDB: filter by entire embedded field value

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

I'm to insert a record with embedded field in OrientDB and then to query for that record using filter:

```
insert into MyClass set embeddedField = {'@type': 'd', 'id': 1}
```

works well, and

```
select from MyClass
```

returns the record I've added. But when I add where with filter for embeddedField, I get no results:

```
select from MyClass where embdeddedField = {'@type': 'd', 'id': 1}
```

I thought that it could happen because Orient adds @version field into embedded document, so I tried to search with version:

```
select from MyClass where embdeddedField = {'@type': 'd', '@version': 0, 'id': 1}
```

But still got no results.

**Question**: Any idea how to filter embedded field by entire document? Without the need to filter explicitly by each field of embedded document:

```
select from MyClass
where embdeddedField.id = 1 
and embdeddedField.field2 = val2
and embeddedField.field3 = val3
```

Because for several reasons I would like to pass the entire object as single query parameter:

```
select from MyClass where embdeddedField = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the provided Hash is transformed to an embedded class.

Perhaps take a look at the ActiveOrientWiki   https://github.com/topofocus/active-orient/wiki/Relations

To explain: 
Take a class `base`, there a  document with two properties (schemaless) 
and add existing documents to it

```rb
( 0..9 ).each do | b |
    base_record= Base.create label: b, first_list: []
    ( 0..9 ).each {|c| base_record.first_list << FirstList.create( label: c ) }
 end
INFO->CREATE VERTEX base CONTENT {"label":0,"first_list":[]}
INFO->CREATE VERTEX first_list CONTENT {"label":0}
INFO->update #136:0 set first_list = first_list || [#147:0]   return after @this
```

then links are embedded and the record looks like

```
 => #<Base:0x00000000041a60e0 @metadata={:type=>"d", :class=>"base", :version=>11, :fieldTypes=>"first_list=z", :cluster=>129, :record=>1},
 @attributes={:first_list=>["#149:1", "#150:1", "#151:1", "#152:1", "#145:2", "#146:2", "#147:2", "#148:2", "#149:2", "#150:2"], :label=>"1"}>
```

if you expand the list items, you can query for "@type"

If you add a document without rid, the same thing happens

```
( 0..9 ).each {|c| base_record.first_list << FirstList.new( label: c ) }
20.04.(12:53:59) INFO->update #130:2 set first_list = first_list || [{ @type: 'd' ,@class: 'first_list' ,label: 0 }]   return after @this

INFO->CREATE VERTEX base CONTENT {"label":"c","first_list":[]}
'#130:2'.expand
 => #<Base:0x00000000043927a0 @metadata={:type=>"d", :class=>"base", :version=>11, :fieldTypes=>"first_list=z", :cluster=>130, :record=>2}, 
 @attributes={:first_list=>["#151:12", "#152:12", "#145:13", "#146:13", "#147:13", "#148:13", "#149:13", "#150:13", "#151:13", "#152:13"], :label=>"c"}>
```

If you omit the class-name, only the scope of the rid's changes

```
INFO-> update #132:2 set first_list = first_list || { @type: 'd'  ,label: 0 }   return after @this
 => [#<Base:0x0000000003a26fb8 @metadata={:type=>"d", :class=>"base", :version=>3, :fieldTypes=>"first_list=z", :cluster=>132, :record=>2}, 
@attributes={:first_list=>["#3:0"], :label=>"d"}>]
```

In any case, a query for `@type` failes

Comment: But my question is about embedded field and not the link

Comment: And anyway I'm hardly can see how this link can be considered as an answer to the question I asked